# Get complete word from string in lines , java?

Tags: java, string

Let us say I have a long string

```
    String s1="This is my world. This has to be broken."
```

I am breaking the above string at a fixed interval of string length let's say when it's 10.

So the output I get after breaking is

```
    This is my
    world. Thi
    s has to b
    e broken.
```

Where as I want that the string should contain complete words and not broken words.

Just like this I want the output to be

```
    This is my
    world.
    This has 
    to be 
    broken.
```

How can I achieve the above output.

Comment: You want to split on "." ?

Comment: Your best bet is to split on space, give your self a variance on 10 characters , if you are over your variance by a defined percentage , the word must be forced on a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String line = "element1 element2 element3";

String [] separatedList = line.split("\\s+");

for (String stringSeparated : separatedList) {
    System.out.println(stringSeparated);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand the logic of the program, but you can use String.indexOf(' ') or something like that to know where exactly are the spaces of your string. check here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_indexof.htm and read the documentation [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28int%29)

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines?

```
int limit = 10;

// Tokenize words
String s1="This is my world. This has to be broken.";
final String[] words = s1.split( " " );

// Apply word-wrapping
final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for( String word : words ) {
    if( sb.length() + word.length() > limit ) {
        // Next word wraps
        System.out.println( sb );
        sb.setLength( 0 );
    }
    else {
        // Otherwise add to current line
        if( sb.length() > 0 ) sb.append( ' ' );
    }
    sb.append( word );
}

// Handle final line
System.out.println( sb );
```